# how to remove a vector element c++

Tags: c++, class, object, oop, vector

I am trying to create a record list using two classes. One class `enterrecords` is for entering the values while the other class `records` is for gathering them, organizing them, and printing them. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class enterrecords
{
    public:
    string name;
    int age;
    string color;

    enterrecords() 
    {
        name = "";
        age = 0;
        color = "";
    }
    enterrecords(string n, int a, string b) 
    {
        name = n;
        age = a;
        color = b;
    }

};
class records
{
    public:
    vector <enterrecords> list;
    records()
    {

    }
    void addtolist(const enterrecords s)
    {
        this->list.push_back(s);
    }
    void print()
    {
        rank();
        cout << endl;
        for (const auto& it : this->list)
        {
            cout << it.name << " " << it.age << " " << it.color << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    void rank()
    {
        sort(list.begin(), list.end(), [](const auto& r1, const auto& r2) {return r1.age < r2.age; });
    }
    void remove(int r)
    {
        list.erase(list.begin() + r-1);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    enterrecords s1;
    enterrecords s2;
    enterrecords s3;
    enterrecords s4;
    records c1;
    s1 = enterrecords("john", 21, "pink");
    s2 = enterrecords("male", 25, "orange");
    s3 = enterrecords("rob", 23, "blue");
    s4 = enterrecords("casie", 31, "red");
    c1.addtolist(s1);
    c1.addtolist(s2);
    c1.addtolist(s3);
    c1.addtolist(s4);
    c1.print();
}
```

The code above automatically sorts the people from youngest to oldest. The problem, however, is that only people aged 30 and below can be on the record list. Anyone aged 31 and up will have their record ignored or deleted. So if I did `c1.addtolist(s4)`, it should invalidate their record. Ideally, `s4` will be removed from the vector that holds all the record elements.

Here is the current output of this program:

```
john 21 pink

rob 23 blue

male 25 orange

casie 31 red
```

Here would be the desired output of the program:

```
john 21 pink

rob 23 blue

male 25 orange
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Side note: Might be simpler to not add if > 31.

Comment: Did you try using your `remove` function? You could also just not add to the vector in the `addtolist` function if the requirements aren't met.

Comment: When removing an item from the vector, do you want the remaining values in slots moved "up"?

Comment: If you are using c++20 or later, [`erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) is probably the simplest way

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
list.erase(
    remove_if(
        list.begin(),
        list.end(),
        [] ( enterrecords t )
{
    return( t.age > 30 );
} ),
list.end() );
```

Note that there is a STL container called 'list'.  Calling your vector of records `list` is a bit confusing.

Here is the complete program code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class enterrecords
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    string color;

    enterrecords()
    {
        name = "";
        age = 0;
        color = "";
    }
    enterrecords(string n, int a, string b)
    {
        name = n;
        age = a;
        color = b;
    }

};
class records
{
public:
    vector <enterrecords> myRecords;
    records()
    {

    }
    void add(const enterrecords& s)
    {
        myRecords.push_back(s);
    }
    void print()
    {
        remove();
        rank();
        cout << endl;
        for (const auto& it : myRecords)
        {
            cout << it.name << " "
                 << it.age << " "
                 << it.color << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    void rank()
    {
        sort(myRecords.begin(), myRecords.end(),
             [](const auto& r1, const auto& r2)
        {
            return r1.age < r2.age;
        });
    }
    void remove()
    {
        myRecords.erase(
            remove_if(
                myRecords.begin(),
                myRecords.end(),
                [] ( enterrecords t )
        {
            return( t.age > 30 );
        } ),
        myRecords.end() );
    }
};

int main()
{
    records c1;
    c1.add(enterrecords("john", 21, "pink"));
    c1.add(enterrecords("male", 25, "orange"));
    c1.add(enterrecords("rob", 23, "blue"));
    c1.add(enterrecords("casie", 31, "red"));
    c1.print();
}
```

Comment: And `list` is potentially even worse when coupled with `using namespace std;` cluttering up the global namespace.